# Python запрос к базе данных

Tags: python, sql, telebot

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть вот такая таблица

Как по номеру user_id достать merchant_id?

Вот такой код у меня:

```
def worker_merchant_id(user_id):
try:
    with sqlite3.connect("evidence.db") as con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        result = cur.execute('SELECT `merchant_id` FROM `ticket` WHERE `user_id` = ?', (user_id,)).fetchall()
        for row in result:
            return row[1]
except:
    pass
```

и в другом файле:

```
chat_id = call.message.chat.id
user_name = call.message.chat.username
MerchantId = database.worker_merchant_id(chat_id)
```

После того как он получит merchant_id, в зависимости от него он должен отправить сообщение, но этого не происходит, в моих подозрения, что он просто его не получает.

Comment: может return row[0]? У вас же 1 только поле возвращается

Comment: https://prnt.sc/12iei2v выходит нижняя ошибка

Comment: https://prnt.sc/12ieqmg в другом варианте стоит * вместо merchant_id

Comment: ну так уберите блок `try except` и посмотрите какая ошибка будет в консоли.

Comment: попробуйте так.
cursor.execute(f"SELECT merchant_id FROM ticket where user_id={user_id}")
    if cursor.fetchone()==None: return "нету". только fetchone в отдельную переменную, что бы потом можно было с этим работать

Comment: если стоит * то merchant_id  будет явно не 1 элементом тоже.

Comment: Такая обработка ошибок как у вас гораздо хуже чем ее полное отсутствие. Вы же даже не поймёте что не так и код тихо продолжит работать